# Assigning random numbers to an array and checking for duplicates

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i was given an assignment to create an array of 100 elements and assign it random values using rand () function and to check if there are duplicates within the array or not. I have completed the code and its running fine but i'm not sure whether its actually checking for duplicates or just printing duplicates not found as i have run it many times but it has not shown " duplicate values found" for a single time even

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
    int array1[100];
    for (int a=0; a<100; a++)
    {
        array1[a]=rand();
        cout<<array1[a]<<endl;
    }
    for(int b=0;b<100;b++)
    {
        for(int c=b+1;c<100;c++)
        {
            if(array1[b]==array1[c])
            {
                cout<<"Array contains duplicates\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"No Duplicates found"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into `std::unique` if your assignment permits it. It makes for a pretty short and straightforward solution for checking just whether there are duplicates or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since `rand()` returns a value in `[0, RAND_MAX)` it is very unlikely that two of them will be equal in just 100 values (`RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least 32k but probably a lot larger).

You should try narrowing the range of possible numbers that you generate by using modulo operator: `rand()%MAX_VALUE` yields a value in `[0, MAX_VALUE)`.

Actually by interpreting the [pidgeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) if you choose `MAX_VALUE < 100` you must have a duplicate for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is where functions, and function testing comes in useful.  Move your duplicate checking code into its own function.  Then create an array, initialized with values you know contain duplicates, pass that into your new checking function, and see if you get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reviewing your algorithm (which I might or might not understand properly), I'd like to suggest you write some test code.  Make a fake_rand() function that works like rand(), but every 10th number is 0, or something like it. Make that fake function **very** easy to understand, or you have to write test code for it as well.

Then, use  it instead of the real one to test your algo.

Test code is a very useful and powerful concept, take some time to google it.

Comment: testing is a good idea, but I think [Jack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13674207/365496) shows a better way than `fake_rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks to be functionally correct. Keep in mind that the probability of finding duplicates in a set of 100 random numbers (from a total number space of 2^32) is reasonably low, so it's not overly surprising that you haven't found such instances.

Comment: I narrowed random numbers to a maximum of 100. but now its displaying "array contains duplicates" alot of times despite the break i have put in the if statement within the loop.

Comment: The number space need not be bigger than 2^15. It is up to the implementation. As rand returns a non-negative int, I doubt the space is bigger than 2^31.

Comment: That break is only breaking out of the inner loop - if you only want to display the duplicates message once, you could have a (boolean) variable to keep track of whether a duplicate was found, and based on that break out of both loops. (Or even convert your loops into 'while' loops until the variable is 'true')

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. rand always returns the same sequence when not seeded with a different start value. so you should call srand with different seeds (maybe derived from current time), otherwise when they are all different for the first run, they will be all different forever.

Comment: If you change 100 to 100000, then you will see duplos.

Answer (score 0):

As chris has pointed out, using unique is the way to go. As a general rule, don't write your own loops if there is library routine that can do the job.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
bool hasDuplicates(RandomAccessIterator first, 
    RandomAccessIterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>
        ::value_type value_type;

    std::vector<value_type> v(first, last);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    return std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()) != v.end();
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 100;
    int array1[n];

    // Seeding of rand would go here

    std::for_each(array1, array1 + n, 
        [](int& x){ x = std::rand(); });

    bool b = hasDuplicates(array1, array1 + n);

    std::cout << (b ? "Array contains duplicates" :
        "No duplicates found") <<
        std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```